# Random vector, finding CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

We have random vector $(X,Y)$ with distribution
$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{(x,y) $\in (0,1)^2,y>x$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$. Find $F_Z$.

My approach:
$F_Z(t)=P(\frac{Y}{X}<t)=\int_0^1\int_u^{tu}{f_{X,Y}(u,v)dvdu}=\int^1_02(tu-u)du=2*\frac{1}{2}u^2(t-1)]^1_0=t-1.$ Which is wrong. Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing everything in terms of indicators, one gets
\begin{align}
F_Z(t)&=2\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<y<1}\mathbf{1}_{y/x\leq  t}dxdy\\&=2\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1} \mathbf{1}_{0<y<1} \mathbf{1}_{ x<y}\mathbf{1}_{y\leq  tx}dxdy\\
&=2\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1}   \mathbf{1}_{x<y\leq  tx}\mathbf{1}_{y<1}dxdy\\
&=2\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1}   \mathbf{1}_{x<y\leq  \min\{tx,1\}} dxdy.
\end{align}
Note that for $t\lt 1$ and $x>0$, $\mathbf{1}_{x<y\leq  \min\{tx,1\}}\leq\mathbf{1}_{x<y\leq   tx,1}=0$ (which is logical, since $Z=Y/X\geqslant 1$). For $t\geq 1$, integrating first over $y$, we get
$$
F_Z(t)=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1} (\min\{tx,1\}-x)dx
=2\int_0^1 \min\{tx,1\}dx-1.$$
Splitting the integral at $1/t$ gives
$$
F_Z(t)=2\int_0^{1/t}txdx+2\int_{1/t}^1dx-1=\frac 1t+2-\frac 2t
-1=1-\frac 1t$$
hence we derive that
$$
F_Z(t)=\left(1-\frac 1t\right)\mathbf{1}_{t\geq 1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$Z>1$ so you need $F_Z(t)$ only for $t>1$.

You need $ tu<1$ in your inside integral, so the outside integral is from $0$ to $\frac 1   t$ if the inside one is from $u$ to $tu$. There is also an integral w.r.t. $u$ from $\frac 1  t $ to $1$ and in this, the inside integral would be from $u$ to $1$.

$F_Z(t)=\int_{(1/t)}^{1}\int_u^{1} f_{X,Y}(u,v)dvdu +\int_{0}^{1/t}\int_u^{tu} f_{X,Y}(u,v)dvdu$.